# .NET base 64 encoder. When will i have to write custom encode for it?

Tags: .net, base64, encoder

The .net provides its own implementation of converting to/from base64 encoding but sometime i see people writing their own encodes. Just wondering what could be the real life applications where you will have to write your custom encoder rather using the one that .net provides

Comment: Where have you seen people writing their own? I haven't heard of that

Comment: http://dotnet.sys-con.com/node/192527

Comment: Your link is about *understanding* a base64 encoder.  Other than that, there's no reason to write your own.

Comment: @yodaj007 Excrept from that link "A Lightweight Custom Base64 Encoder
The .NET Framework's ToBase64-String() and FromBase64String() methods will meet most of your Base64 encoding needs. However what if you are developing a system and need a slightly different encoding scheme? For instance, you may want to use a different character set than the normal{"A"-"Z," "a"-"z," "0"-9," "+," "/"} set. In this section I'll present a lightweight, custom Base64 encoder written in C# "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These generally occur in code ported from another environment.

.Net has sufficient Bas64 capabilities in `Convert.ToBase64String` and `System.Security.Cryptography.ToBase64Transform`; there is no need to write your own.